# REACT - Renderizar otro componente si el usuario esta logueado

Tags: reactjs, firebase, login, react-hooks, usestate

¿Como andan?

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma en React JS + Firebase y me encuentro con la siguiente situación:

Si el usurio NO esta logueado se debe renderizar un componente que es la pantalla principal y si el usuario SI esta logueado se debe renderizar otro componente.

Lo que se me ocurrió para resolverlo es crear una función que pregunte a Firebase si el usuario está logueado y según la respuesta setear un estado en true o false.

Después con un operador ternario renderizar el componente que corresponde.

Sucede que a veces funciona y a veces no. Supongo que será por una cuestión de como funciona el useState pero no logro dar con el error.

Quizás haya una forma mas adecuada de resolver esta situación, si a alguien se le ocurre sería un 10.

Aquí el código:

```js
function App() {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    loginCheck();
  }, []);
  const loginCheck = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      setUserState(true);
    } else {
      setUserState(false);
    }
  };
  const login = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        setUserState(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        const email = error.email;
        const credential = provider.credentialFromError(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      {userState ? <ListaClases /> : <Splash login={login} />}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías describir más el "_a veces funciona y a veces no_". O sea, ¿A veces te da que está logueado cuando no lo está o es que te loguea sin estar logueado, o las dos?

Comment: Si claro. 
Por lo general no reconoce que el usuario está logueado.
Cuando hago el proceso de login con una cuenta nueva si funciona, aunque si actualizo la web ya no reconoce al usuario logueado.

Comment: Intenta lo siguiente,  comenta el `useEffect` y el `loginCheck`. Agrega debajo del `useState` la línea `getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => setUserState(!!user))` y prueba si funciona.

Comment: no es necesario ir hasta firebase para saber si el usuario está autenticado o no, firebase te devuelve un token JWT, decodificalo y determina si la fecha de expiración del token es mayor a la hora actual.

Comment: Será que la sesión no es persistente? para este caso deberías guardar la sesión en `localStorage` o bien en una `Cookie` Esto dado a que indicas que al refrescar se pierde la sesión.